# multiple persistent volume claims on the same persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am working with kubernetes for a long time and I have a question that I am not sure what the answer is.

If I create a `PersistentVolume` and couple of `PersistentVolumeClaims` that uses that `PersistentVolume`.
I mapped different `PersistentVolumeClaims` to different pods/containers.

Is There a way that one pod could read data that the other pod/container written?

Comment: What kind of persistent volume is it? You may want to give a look at ReadWriteMany support for persistent volumes ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/ )

Comment: It doesn't matter which kind, I just wanted to know if it is possible that by mistake, one pod will have permission to see data that he shouldn't see because of using the same persistentvolume across several pods

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** By mistake - no. By a chain of mistakes - yes.

First, PV [Access Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) need to be set to `ReadWriteMany`.

Then, a specific Volume Plugin have to be used. While Kuberentes supports a lot of different volumes, only few support `ReadWriteMany` Access Mode.
Those volume types that do support `ReadWriteMany` can be found in [this table](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) (scroll down a bit).

As far as a container is concerned, PersistentVolume is just a volume mounted in container's filesystem. If you mount it to multiple pods, they will be able to read and write to the same files.

Comment: but for every container you connect a different persistentVolumeClaim, so although you still using the same persistentVolume, you are using a different claim.                                               Is it still possible that by mistake one container that uses different claim but the same persistentVolume will get access to the other container claim and data?